# i want to get message in textarea in ckeditor based on the selected dropdown means based on selected id in laravel 10

Tags: laravel

[database table name template_masters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NiGx.png)[database table name template_messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEqbr.png)
[template master listing view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Yq5.png)[form to display message in the ckeditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btXAA.png)

web.php page

```
Route::get('/template_message_send', [MessageController::class, 'template_message_index'])->name('template_message_send.index');
Route::get('/template_message_send/create', [MessageController::class, 'template_message_create'])->name('template_message_send.create');
Route::post('/template_message_send/send_message', [MessageController::class, 'template_send_message'])->name('template_message_send.send_message');
```

MessageController.php

```
public function template_message_index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = TemplateMessage::orderByDesc('id')
            ->leftJoin('template_masters', 'template_messages.template_id', '=', 'template_masters.id')
            ->select('template_messages.id', 'template_masters.template_name', 'template_messages.mobile', 'template_messages.template_message', 'template_messages.image', 'template_messages.created_at');

            return Datatables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->addColumn('multidelete', function ($row) {
                        $actionBtn = '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="'.$row->id.'" data-id="'.$row->id.'" class="message_checkbox">';
                        return $actionBtn;
                    })
                    ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                            $actionBtn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">View</a>
                            <button class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm mx-1 data-delete" data-id="'.$row->id.'">Delete</button>';
                            return $actionBtn;
                    })
                    ->addColumn('template_message', function ($row) {
                        if($row->message){
                            $linkTag = $row->message;
                        }else{
                            $linkTag = 'No message available';
                        }
                        return $linkTag;
                    })
                    ->addColumn('image', function ($row) {
                        if($row->image){
                            $url= asset('photos/'.$row->image);
                            $linkTag = '<a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="'.$url.'"><img src="'.$url.'" width="70" height="70" style="border-radius:5px;"></a>';
                        }else{
                            $linkTag = 'No image available';
                        }
                        return $linkTag;
                    })
                    ->addColumn('created_at', function ($row) {
                        $dateString = $row->created_at;
                        // Convert to Indian time zone
                        $indianTime = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($dateString)->setTimezone('Asia/Kolkata');
                        // Format as 12-hour time with AM/PM
                        return $indianTime->format('d-m-Y h:i:s A');
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action','multidelete','image','created_at'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
        return view ('template_message_send.index');
    }

    public function template_message_create()
    {
        $data = TemplateMaster::all(); 
        return view ('template_message_send.create',['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

create.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('template_message_send.send_message') }}" class="forms-sample" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    {{-- <div class="form-group">
        <span style="color:red;"> NOTE: At least one field is required from Message and Image to send message on whatsapp. </span>
    </div> --}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleTextarea1">Template Name</label>
        <select name="template_id" id="templateInput" class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Template Name</option>
            @foreach($data as $row)
                <option value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->template_name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputMobile">Mobile Numbers</label><span style="color:red;"> *</span>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" value="{{ old('mobile')}}" class="form-control" id="exampleInputMobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" oninput="addCountryCode(this)">
        <small id="mobileExample" class="form-text text-muted">Example: 919758965665, 919865655568, 918879568956, 919865655568, ...</small>
        <br>
        @error('mobile')
            <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
        @if($errors->has('mobile') && !empty($errors->get('mobile')[0]) && str_contains($errors->get('mobile')[0], 'regex'))
            <div class="text-danger">Please enter valid 10-digit mobile numbers separated by commas.</div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleTextarea1">Your Template Message</label>
        <textarea name="template_message" id="editor" rows="3">{!! $row->message !!}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="file-upload-default">
        <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
            <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" class="form-control file-upload-info">
            <span class="input-group-append">
                <button class="file-upload-browse btn btn-primary" type="button">Upload</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Additional error message for both message and image empty -->
        @if(session('errors') && session('errors')->has('message') && session('errors')->has('image'))
            <div class="text-danger">Please provide a message or an image to send on WhatsApp.</div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Send Template Message</button>
    {{-- <button class="btn btn-light">Cancel</button> --}}
</form>
<script>
    function addCountryCode(input) {
        var inputValues = input.value.trim().split(',').map(function(item) {
            return item.trim();
        });

        var updatedValues = inputValues.map(function(value) {
            return value.startsWith('91') ? value : '91' + value;
        });

        input.value = updatedValues.join(', ');
    }

    // Success Alert Start
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('errorAlert').style.display = 'none';
    }, 5000);
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/41.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then( editor => {
                console.log( editor );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
```

i am doing in the laravel 10
this is all my code is given below:

in which i am trying to get message form the template_masters in the ck editor based on the template_name's id.

if user select any template_name from dropdown i want to display message based on template_name's id in text area from template_masters database table using ajax in laravel 10